# Fail to fetch any view after passport authentication

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, ejs

I am building an application using node.js and express.js with passport authentication using MVC Architecture. I have strictly followed a tutorial on how to implement and integrate passport authentication using a local strategy. It seems like the strategy is working fine. In my controller which is handling the authentication (using passport.authenticate), successRedirect is always executed given that I submit matching details with an instance in the database. However, after redirecting to wherever successRedirect points to, I am getting a GET request Error 500. Afterwards, if I try to access other routes, I still get the same error, thus failing to display the desired view template. However, if I try to access the same routes without attempting to login, the GET request executes successfully with statusCode 200.

The exact error I get is :
GET /dashboard 500 4.313 ms - 941

users.js route

```
var usersController = require('../../controllers/usersController');

/* POST login */
router.post('/login', usersController.loginAccount);
```

usersController.js

```
module.exports.loginAccount = function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: 'dashboard',
        failureRedirect: '/users/login',
        failureFlash: true
    }) (req, res, next);
}
```

index.js route

```
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, indexController.dashboardPage);

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();
    else{
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Please log in to view this resource');
        res.redirect('/users/login');
    }
}
```

Command line after attempting login:
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `username`, `password`, `address`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `clients` AS `client` WHERE `client`.`username` = 'nikolaisennn' LIMIT 1;
Serializing user 
POST /users/login 302 144.266 ms - 74 
Deserializing user 
User ID: 65 
GET /dashboard 500 4.313 ms - 941

I have been stuck on this issue for a while, tried to find solutions online but I haven't really managed to find what I need. I am sure that there is something small that I am missing, yet I have no clue what it is.

Comment: I have some fresh insight on the problem. When successRedirect is executed, i get <br/> GET /dashboard 500 4.313 ms - 941 and the page actually displayed is layout.ejs (which had no real content, so I couldn't realize that this page was rendered before).

Comment: I solved the issue. Was using <%= body %> instead of <%- body %> in layout.ejs.